# Why would I be getting a NoSuchMethodError at super.onCreate() for registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks in Android?

Tags: android

I have been receiving this error:

```
02-06 14:14:33.984 2806-2806/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.ibm.cher.tabatha, PID: 2806
                                             java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentManager$FragmentLifecycleCallbacks;Z)V in class Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager' appears in /data/app/com.ibm.cher.tabatha-1/base.apk:classes9.dex)
                                                 at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleDispatcher$DispatcherActivityCallback.onActivityCreated(LifecycleDispatcher.java:75)
                                                 at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:197)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:961)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityDonut.onCreate(BaseFragmentActivityDonut.java:41)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:315)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
                                                 at com.ibm.cher.tabatha.tabatha_mobile_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

It seems to happen when the AVD I am running crashes during compilation and then never fixes itself. I have tried invalidating cache and restarting as well as doing a complete rebuild of the project with no success. These are my gradle files for the project as well as the sub project causing this error.

build.gradle(subproject)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ibm.cher.tabatha"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':shared')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex'
    compile files('libs/watson-iot-0.2.6.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.androidplot:androidplot-core:1.5.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho.android.service-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.1.jar')
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-rc1';
    compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-rc1';
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-rc1';
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-rc1';
}


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
}
```

build.gradle(overall project)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3') {
        force = true
    }

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Has anybody else gotten this specific error or ran into something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the version of appcompat? (in your posted code there is just a colon). Same for multidex.

Does another library in your dependencies bring in another version of appcompat that is older?

You should try adding the version. If it's not working after that try adding force=true to your appcompat dependency.

Also:  I am not sure, but multidex might be dependent on certain build tools/Gradle versions,so you might want to update everything to the latest version.

Also try building without instant run and try deinstalling/reinstalling  app from avd via adb.

Essentially there is 2 possibilities I can see : either in your class path is a version of appcompat that has not the method you are calling or multidex is not able to put the stuff in the right dex files. For the latter you might have to look into the documentation by Google. There are ways to change which dex files contain which classes and the order of loading (I think).

Comment: There is only a colon there in my code. Could that be the problem? And the device im using (not the AVD im testing on) is restricted to API 25 so I have to work under those constraints. Which versions are compatible with API 25?

Comment: Yes I think that might be the problem. When building android studio might just take whatever version it "can find".

Comment: What is the best way to find out which library I have installed and are there specific ones that work for API 25 and before only?

Comment: You can update the buildtools and the target sdk but keep the minsdk lower. They will be compatible with the old Android versions. For multidex read this :https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-on-l. It seems like you could remove the multidex library because your minsdk is higher than 21.

Comment: You should find our which is the newest version of appcompat and use that explicitly. They should not be dependent on the min API level because that is mostly the point of using appcompat in the first place but I think they might be dependent on the target sdk sometimes. Read this for more info https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html#revisions

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed my problem. It was the not having a version set. I now have the compiling SDK as 27 but have my target one 25 and it works.