# Application keeps crashing on start when apk is build using mac

Tags: android

I have an android project, When i build the project using mac application crashes on start. When same is done using Windows system it works fine.
Error log is pasted below.

I have tried all the available solutions here [Why would I be getting a NoSuchMethodError at super.onCreate() for registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650473/why-would-i-be-getting-a-nosuchmethoderror-at-super-oncreate-for-registerfragm/48650672)

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentManager$FragmentLifecycleCallbacks;Z)V in class Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager' appears in /data/app/android.form.avss.prepaidcard-2/base.apk:classes11.dex)
      at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleDispatcher$DispatcherActivityCallback.onActivityCreated(LifecycleDispatcher.java:75)
      at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:219)
      at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1039)
      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityDonut.onCreate(BaseFragmentActivityDonut.java:39)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:297)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.o nCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
      at android.form.avss.prepaidcard.ihmf_form_fill.ui.Activities.FormBaseActivity.onCreate(FormBaseActivity.java:30)
      at android.form.avss.prepaidcard.ihmf_form_fill.ui.Activities.FormFillActivity.onCreate(FormFillActivity.java:147)
```

Below is the app gradle config. and dependencies i am using.
Client restricted the sdk versions to 23, so i can't update it. I have tried updating compiled version but no luck.

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.form.prepaidcard"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    compile('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.2.5'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'

    //network library
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    //IHMF dependencies
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$lifecycle_version"

    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'

//    compile 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1'
//    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
//    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Currently i am clueless as apk installed using windows runs smooth.
i can't decide if its code or build level issue. I always have to push the code to Github in order to debug code in window. Which consumes a lot of times.

Any  help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This response isn't a definite answer, but it's too long to put in a comment.

I have the feeling this is a multi-dex issue with a dependency that is shared amongst modules. It seems to be complaining about support v4 libraries.

In the command window you could run `./gradlew :app:dependencies | grep v4` and see which version don't equal `23.4.0` and then exclude that module from those dependencies.

Or you can take a heavy handed approach and resolve it at the top level and try to force the version:

```
allprojects {
    ...

    configurations {
        all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thnks. I will try it.